# WAMP Could not execute menu item (internal error)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

Seen this post in a few places but still havn't resolved this issue for me.

I'm using *Windows 8* with *WAMP Server 2.4* / *Apache 2.4.4* listening at port 80 and *PHP 5.4.12*.

Both localhost and 127.0.0.1 do resolve the admin page. No problem here, but when I leftclick in the traybar at the wamp icon (which is green for the record), and choose localhost or phpmyadmin I get this error and I still seem unable to browse my internet IP from ie. my phone in this case.

Also for the record, the test port 80 option show Apache is using it.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you share the screenshot here?

Comment: It is a Windows alert message [link](http://oi43.tinypic.com/sdnt46.jpg)

Comment: The last sentence says 'catalogue name wrong'.

Comment: Do you even need the traybar stuff?

Comment: Agree, priority I figure has something to do with path settings and maby the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of WAMP do you use? Try 32 bits instead of 64 bits

Comment: 2.4 Maby I'll try that. But it also seem to be setting related since it stastes directory path wrong. But it works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are running the 64bit WAMPServer you still need the 32bit version of

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582
```

This is because `wampmanager` thats the `W` icon in the system tray is still 32bit and uses this runtime library.